# Cloned Items does not give change information when original item is updated through Unicorn Sync

Tags: unicorn, serialization, item-clones

I am using `Sitecore 9 Update 2`

I created the site and serialized it using Unicorn. I also created a clone of this site.

Based on the documentation here https://doc.sitecore.com/users/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/clones.html, when there is a field change in the clone item, then we change the same field in the original item, it would then give a notification on the cloned item that the original had a change.

We can see it like so
[image]

However, when I change the field of the cloned item then the field of the original item was updated through Unicorn sync, the notification does not show up in the cloned item anymore which causes me to not be able to Accept or Reject the change.

I tried updating my serialization file to set UpdateLinkDatabase and enableTransparentSync to True, but it did not work.

Is this a bug in Sitecore clone or am I just missing something?